# Xamarin android Fly out menu with FragmentTabHost is not working properly

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm working on an app and want to integrate the navigation Fly out menu with the Fragment Tab Host but problem is with the Tab Widget which is always hang on the top of the fragment all the properties like align parent bottom, gravity bottom is not working.

Any Suggestions

Comment: Can you show the AXML of your layout and code behind?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Demo.Droid.Fragment.FlyOutContainer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/FlyOutContainer">
    <include
        layout="@menu/MenuLayout" />
    <include
        layout="@layout/ContentLayout" />
</Demo.Droid.Fragment.FlyOutContainer>